# Cannot show jquery datables with php json_encode?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

i try to get curl data to jquery data table (like this https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html),

Here is the response.php

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

the json_encode output:

```
{
 "hittotal":69511,
 "data":[
   {
       "....."
       },.....
     ]
}
```

HTML table and javascript in my  web page(datatables.php):

```
<script>
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>message:</td>'+
        '<td>'+(d.message)+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>id:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.id+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+

'</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

    "ajax": {
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'response.php',
    'data': {
       from: '<? echo $from; ?>',
       to: '<? echo $to; ?>'

    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "datetime" },
        { "data": "message" },

    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
     }
  } );
 } );
</script>
```

html :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>datetime</th>
            <th>message</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>datetime</th>
            <th>message</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

i am sure echo json_encode($results) is not empty but why cannot shown in data tables ?

Comment: I see you are using datatables.  Are you actually using the jquery datatables package?

Comment: yes , i am using  jquery datatables package

Comment: a few notes.  I noticed that you are using $('#example').DataTable();, however I dont see where you name the table id='example', this would mean that the datatable package has no idea where to apply itself to.  
Can you give me a small description on how it is working currently?  Are you able to see a simple datatable if you dont included the php portion?  Thanks!

Comment: actually ,i want to using https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html as you said, but my data is from server side (php) ,so i don't know how to modify it

Comment: can you post an example of the returned data?

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Kyle Pastor: have any idea ?

Comment: There are many issues with the above code.  Have you been able to make a simple example of datatables?  You should try to just put in some example data (no php) in the table and then see if you can do what you want with it.

Comment: kyle Pastor,i have update my question with more data , can you help to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the child functionality in datatables: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Instead of having the extra information you see in the example you could put table rows instead.

Comment: i have update my code ,and try to get data from php, but it's cannot work ,can you help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: I will take a look today and hopefully get you on the right track.

Comment: Kyle Pastor,thanks for your help and i will be waiting for you ,thanks a lot